# How to trigger form input pattern validation without submitting?

Tags: html, validation, form-submit

I have a form:

```
<form action="/index.html" method="POST" id="form">
    <div id="namediv">
        Full Name: 
        <input type="text" pattern="[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+"/ id="name" required/></div>
    <div>
       Date:            
        <input type="date"/>
    </div>
    <div id="emaildiv">
        Email:
        <input type="email" id="email" onblur="validateEmail()" required/><br>
        <emailerror class="invisible">Incorrect email address!</emailerror>
    </div>
    <div id="urldiv">
        Favorite webpage: 
        <input type="url"   name="favurl"id="url" onblur="validateFavURL()" required/><br>
        <urlerror class="invisible">Incorrect webpage!</urlerror>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Validate" onclick="validateAll()"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I trigger the name's pattern validity without submitting the form? I tried checkValidity() but didn't succeed. What is the exact syntax for it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I clearly understand the question. But the problem appears to be invalid regex. But the field does say "full name" so you'd likely need to allow a space as well.

```html
<div>
  <label>This field accepts upper and lowercase letters only</label>
</div>
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Z][a-z]+" id="name" required/>
```